# Why isn't this route working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have the following route to display the cars of a user:

```
get 'cars/id:/all' => 'wikipages#index', as: 'cars_index'
```

This translates to:

```
cars_index_path     GET     /cars/id:/all(.:format)     cars#index
```

However, when I visit `site-url/cars/1/all` I get the error `No route matches`. Am I visiting the route/path incorrectly?

P.S. Controller method:

```
  def index
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @cars = @user.garage.cars.all
  end
```

Comment: have you tried this `get 'cars/:id/all' => 'wikipages#index', as: 'cars_index'`

Comment: Looking at literally any example from the Rails routing guides should have been enough for you to spot your typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable segments use a leading `:`, not a trailing `:`.

You need `:id`, not `id:`.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! Sorry, I missed that.